# Excel Conversion of .xls to .xlsx using Java

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx, xls

I am trying to extract test output results in excel format. I want the results to be summarized in neat columns and row formats and want to display results graphically using a Pie chart.
To do this, I have used Apache POI API(Excel edits) and JFreeChart(for Pie chart creation).
I have been able to do all this, and the results are generated in .xls format.

When I tried to convert it to xlsx format after all of this, its doing the job, but the Pie chart and other excel stylings are missed to be written to .xlsx output file.

The code I have used for conversion from .xls to .xlsx is as follows:

```
package excelFileGenerate6;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

//import com.aspose.cells.SaveFormat;

public class conversion_to_xlsx {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException,
    IOException {

String inpFn = "C:\\Users\\Username\\JavaProjects\\workspace\\Sample2\\src\\excelFileGenerate6\\report.xls"; 
String outFn = "C:\\Users\\Username\\JavaProjects\\workspace\\Sample2\\src\\excelFileGenerate6\\converted_report.xlsx"; 

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inpFn);
try {
    Workbook wbIn = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
    File outF = new File(outFn);
    if (outF.exists())
        outF.delete();

    Workbook wbOut = new XSSFWorkbook();
    int sheetCnt = wbIn.getNumberOfSheets();
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetCnt; i++) {
        Sheet sIn = wbIn.getSheetAt(i);
        //Sheet sOut = wbOut.getSheet(null);
        Sheet sOut = wbOut.createSheet(sIn.getSheetName());
        Iterator<Row> rowIt = sIn.rowIterator();
        while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
            Row rowIn = rowIt.next();
            Row rowOut = sOut.createRow(rowIn.getRowNum());

            Iterator<Cell> cellIt = rowIn.cellIterator();
            while (cellIt.hasNext()) {
                Cell cellIn = cellIt.next();
                Cell cellOut = rowOut.createCell(
                        cellIn.getColumnIndex(), cellIn.getCellType());

                switch (cellIn.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getErrorCellValue());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    cellOut.setCellFormula(cellIn.getCellFormula());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                }

                {
                    CellStyle styleIn = cellIn.getCellStyle();
                    CellStyle styleOut = cellOut.getCellStyle();
                    styleOut.setDataFormat(styleIn.getDataFormat());
                }
                cellOut.setCellComment(cellIn.getCellComment());

                // HSSFCellStyle cannot be cast to XSSFCellStyle
                // cellOut.setCellStyle(cellIn.getCellStyle());
            }
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outF);
    try {
        wbOut.write(out);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
}
}
```

I have generated the excel reports and associated Pie chart using HSSF workbook style which gives the excel output in .xls format. Tried the online help to convert the HSSF objects to XSSF objects , but the pie chart creation gave a sun/image/codec error.

Attaching the Screenshots of code snippets and excel output files.
Any code/direction for converting my .xls results to .xlsx format will highly be of help for me..

Thanks
[image: xls-piechart]

The code used to create Pie Chart :

```
package excelFileGenerate6;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFClientAnchor;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset; 
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.PieSectionLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities; 
import java.util.Iterator;

public class CreatePieChartExample {  

        public void createPie(String Filename) throws IOException {
                
                /* Read Excel and the Chart Data */
                FileInputStream chart_file_input = new FileInputStream(new File(Filename));
                /* Read data into HSSFWorkbook */
                HSSFWorkbook my_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(chart_file_input);
                /* This worksheet contains the Pie Chart Data */
                HSSFSheet my_sheet = my_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                /* Create JFreeChart object that will hold the Pie Chart Data */
                DefaultPieDataset my_pie_chart_data = new DefaultPieDataset();
                /* We now iterate over the Excel Workbook data and Populate Pie Chart Data */
                /* Create an Iterator object */
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_sheet.iterator(); 
                /* Loop through worksheet data and populate Pie Chart Dataset */
                String chart_label="a";
                Number chart_data=0;            
                while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                        //Read Rows from Excel document
                        Row row = rowIterator.next();  
                        //Read cells in Rows and get chart data
                        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); 
                                        switch(cell.getCellType()) { 
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                                chart_data=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                                break;
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                                chart_label=cell.getStringCellValue();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                /* Add data to the data set */          
                my_pie_chart_data.setValue(chart_label,chart_data);
                }               
                /* Create a logical chart object with the chart data collected */
                JFreeChart myPieChart=ChartFactory.createPieChart("Test Results",my_pie_chart_data,true,true,false);
                
                // Add custom colors
                PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) myPieChart.getPlot();
                
                //To create chart labels with only values on pie
                PieSectionLabelGenerator gen = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{1}");
                plot.setLabelGenerator(gen);
                
                plot.setSectionPaint("Passed", Color.GREEN);
                plot.setSectionPaint("Failed", Color.RED);
                plot.setSectionPaint("Pending", Color.black);
                plot.setSectionPaint("Total Time taken (ms)", Color.pink);
                plot.setSectionPaint("Skipped", Color.blue);
                plot.setSectionPaint("How many Sub headers are Passed", Color.yellow);
                plot.setSectionPaint("Total TC's", Color.CYAN);
                

                
                /* Specify the height and width of the Pie Chart */
                int width=640; /* Width of the chart */
                int height=480; /* Height of the chart */
                float quality=1; /* Quality factor */
                /* We don't want to create an intermediate file. So, we create a byte array output stream 
                and byte array input stream
                And we pass the chart data directly to input stream through this */             
                /* Write chart as JPG to Output Stream */
                ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();          
                ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(chart_out,quality,myPieChart,width,height);
                /* We now read from the output stream and frame the input chart data */
                InputStream feed_chart_to_excel=new ByteArrayInputStream(chart_out.toByteArray());
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(feed_chart_to_excel);
                /* Add picture to workbook */
                int my_picture_id = my_workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
                /* We can close Piped Input Stream. We don't need this */
                feed_chart_to_excel.close();
                /* Close PipedOutputStream also */
                chart_out.close();
                /* Create the drawing container */
                HSSFPatriarch drawing = my_sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                /* Create an anchor point */
                ClientAnchor my_anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor();
                /* Define top left corner, and we can resize picture suitable from there */
                my_anchor.setCol1(4);
                my_anchor.setRow1(5);
                /* Invoke createPicture and pass the anchor point and ID */
                HSSFPicture  my_picture = drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, my_picture_id);
                /* Call resize method, which resizes the image */
                my_picture.resize();
                /* Close the FileInputStream */
                chart_file_input.close();               
                /* Write changes to the workbook */
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Filename));
                my_workbook.write(out);
                out.close();            
        }
        
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            CreatePieChartExample chart = new CreatePieChartExample();
            chart.createPie("C:\\Users\\user\\JavaProjects\\workspace\\Sample2\\src\\excelFileGenerate6\\report.xls");
        }
}
```

The code used for .xls to .xlsx conversion:

```
package excelFileGenerate6;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

//import com.aspose.cells.SaveFormat;

public class conversion_to_xlsx {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException,
    IOException {

String inpFn = "C:\\Users\\user\\JavaProjects\\workspace\\Sample2\\src\\excelFileGenerate6\\report.xls"; 
String outFn = "C:\\Users\\user\\JavaProjects\\workspace\\Sample2\\src\\excelFileGenerate6\\converted_report.xlsx"; 

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inpFn);
try {
    Workbook wbIn = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
    File outF = new File(outFn);
    if (outF.exists())
        outF.delete();

    Workbook wbOut = new XSSFWorkbook();
    int sheetCnt = wbIn.getNumberOfSheets();
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetCnt; i++) {
        Sheet sIn = wbIn.getSheetAt(i);
        //Sheet sOut = wbOut.getSheet(null);
        Sheet sOut = wbOut.createSheet(sIn.getSheetName());
        Iterator<Row> rowIt = sIn.rowIterator();
        while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
            Row rowIn = rowIt.next();
            Row rowOut = sOut.createRow(rowIn.getRowNum());

            Iterator<Cell> cellIt = rowIn.cellIterator();
            while (cellIt.hasNext()) {
                Cell cellIn = cellIt.next();
                Cell cellOut = rowOut.createCell(
                        cellIn.getColumnIndex(), cellIn.getCellType());

                switch (cellIn.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getErrorCellValue());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    cellOut.setCellFormula(cellIn.getCellFormula());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                }

                {
                    CellStyle styleIn = cellIn.getCellStyle();
                    CellStyle styleOut = cellOut.getCellStyle();
                    styleOut.setDataFormat(styleIn.getDataFormat());
                }
                cellOut.setCellComment(cellIn.getCellComment());

                // HSSFCellStyle cannot be cast to XSSFCellStyle
                // cellOut.setCellStyle(cellIn.getCellStyle());
            }
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outF);
    try {
        wbOut.write(out);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: You appear not to have any code to add the pie chart to your xlsx. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185057/how-to-create-pie-bar-chart-with-apache-poi-with-xddfdatasource-values-from-cu for example code for pie charts.

Comment: Thanks for the resource @PJFanning. I have added the code for Pie chart which I have used. It has HSSF objects, so the results are in .xls file. If I convert the results to xlsx, the Pie chart image is not carried over to converted xlsx file

Comment: The code you've written explicitly take HSSF data like sheets, rows and cells and copies them to XSSF. You need to do the same for the pie chart data. It won't just move by itself.

Comment: You need to create a XSSFPatriarch and an XSSFPicture. Or you can ditch JFreeChart and create pie chart using the code in the comment I made above.